# HDMI "no signal" to external display

Tags: intel-graphics, hdmi

I'm using 19.10 on an ASUS laptop with an Intel® HD Graphics 505 (Broxton) graphics driver.

I'm trying to repurpose a TV with an HDMI port as an external monitor. System settings can tell that that the monitor is there. However, the display reads "No Signal".

I've looked at syslog and dmesg. I don't see anything that looks relevant to my untrained eyes.

gpu-manager.log might have some relevant information:

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:5a84
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
output 0:
    card0-HDMI-A-1
output 1:
    card0-eDP-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 2
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 1
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
Single card detected
Nothing to do
```

Don't know if it matters, but I switched to Unity a few days ago to get Simple Screen Recorder to work.

Output from: 'xrandr | grep '*' '

```
1280x720      60.00*   59.99    59.86    59.74  
1280x720      60.00*   50.00    59.94
```

as requested

When all else fails, read the manual. The instruction there is to use VGA to connect to computer. I suspect computers didn't have HDMI back when we bought it. USB to VGA adapters are available and reasonably priced. The HDMI works on a windows machine, but with pretty severe overscanning.

Comment: xrandr http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/xrandr.1.html may help: Please run _xrandr | grep '*'_ then highlight and copy the resulting text, return here, and click [edit] then add the resulting text into your question  so all the facts we need are in there. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Thanx foggydude  I've against using the big display after all for now. It's on the maybe later list.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

sucky solution:

1. unplug faulty screen
2. reboot pc
3. replug faulty screen 
   faulty screen now works, but another screen (on dvi) (i have 4) stayed black

**working solution**

1) go to display configuration

2) disable all screens apart from screen that also shows my bios and grub

3) reenable screens 1-by-1

still not happy, i want a working nvidia driver one day

/edit

I have the same problem with Nvidia. The nvidia drivers break my system (x doesnt start, i can only get to a terminal), so i have to use the nouveau driver

the problem might be connected to this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2398740 : the hdmi gives image but no sound output so the screen doesnt understand the signal.

However, i cannot solve it as i cant re-enable HDMI sound output: there is no mention of any hdmi sound output in pavucontrol or any other settings. so im in the dark (sorry for the pun), but maybe it helps us find the answer.

ps: i tried a HDMI to VGA adapter: same result

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: I hoped that that link helped OP solve their problem